# How do I print out a comma multiple times using Boost Preprocessor

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

I need to use a variadic macro to expand to multiple variations of a class. Since they need to have different names based on the macro input I can't simply use templates. The problem is that I can't expand the comma (`,`) symbol, and my class has functions which take multiple parameters (for which I need to use the comma symbol).

`boost` provides the `BOOST_PP_COMMA()` macro which expands to a comma, but it only works outside of loop constructs. I'm guessing the issue is that `BOOST_PP_COMMA()` is expanded once and then treated as a comma, at which point the program breaks.

To illustrate the problem, suppose I have a macro function which takes a variadic number of parameters and produces a number of commas equal to the number of parameters given to it. The naive solution would be this:

```
#define TEST(...)\
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), \
        MACRO, \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))

#define MACRO(z, n, data) BOOST_PP_IF(1,BOOST_PP_COMMA(),BOOST_PP_COMMA())\
```

But this produces a range of errors because the comma is expanded and the macro thinks they're dividing parameters.

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: a redundant set of parentheses maybe, around the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` with a macro that can be called with the expected arguments will work fine, and it even prevents the need for `BOOST_PP_COMMA`:

```
#define PRINT_COMMAS(...)\
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), \
        PRINT_COMMAS_MACRO, \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))

#define PRINT_COMMAS_MACRO(z, n, data) ,
```

[See it work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbaa3b7beaf76b26)

To save the extra macro, you can take advantage of the fact that `BOOST_PP_ENUM` adds commas between expansions by adding one to the number of repetitions and discarding the macro arguments using `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT`:

```
#define PRINT_COMMAS(...)\
    BOOST_PP_ENUM( \
        BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)), \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT(), \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))
```

[See it work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/377eb0885bd3c2d5)

I personally think the first is more clear.

Comment: chris, thanks. I seem to have misrepresented my issue, let me figure out a better isolated example that will illustrate my problem!

Comment: Chris, I've created a new question with a similar problem, but to which I can't seem to get your solution to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770614/how-do-i-expand-a-macro-containing-commas-inside-a-boost-pp-if