# How do I expand a macro containing commas inside a BOOST_PP_IF

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

I asked the following question earlier, but the solution doesn't seem to work in this particular case.

[How do I print out a comma multiple times using Boost Preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770397/how-do-i-print-out-a-comma-multiple-times-using-boost-preprocessor)

I am trying to expand a macro containing a comma conditionally. Here is an example illustrating the problem:

```
#define TEST(...)\
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), \
        MACRO, \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))

#define MACRO(z, n, data) BOOST_PP_IF(1,MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(z, z),MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(z, z))

#define MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(_NAME, _NAME2) _NAME TIBRA_EATEN_COMMA() _NAME2

#define EATEN_COMMA BOOST_PP_IF(1,BOOST_PP_COMMA,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT())
TEST(1,2,3,4)
```

This expands to

> BOOST_PP_IIF BOOST_PP_IIF BOOST_PP_IIF BOOST_PP_IIF

When it should expand to

> 0,0 1,1 2,2 3,3

Comment: Does `BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF` help at all?

Comment: @chris, well this is a simplified example, in my actual code `CODE_CONTAINING_COMMA` is a customised `class` declaration, so I don't think `BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF` is going to help much.

Comment: Well, there is a technique that could also possibly help: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b75fdccefcec6b7c

Comment: Hmm, this expands fine for me as is because the comma is enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: @chris that link looks interesting, I think that's a pretty good solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delay invoking your macro by first selecting it and then invoking it:

```
#define TEST(...)\
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), \
        MACRO, \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))

#define MACRO(z, n, data) BOOST_PP_IF(1,MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA,MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA)(n, n)

#define MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(_NAME, _NAME2) _NAME EATEN_COMMA _NAME2

#define EATEN_COMMA BOOST_PP_IF(1,BOOST_PP_COMMA,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT())()
```

[See it work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/635e9fd105c89f33)

The `IF` invocation expands to either your macro without an invocation or something that discard arguments when invoked. After one is chosen, the last parentheses invoke it with the desired arguments without the commas getting in the way.

Apart from that, I changed `z` to `n` and `TIBRA_EATEN_COMMA()` to `EATEN_COMMA`. As some parts are redundant, you can find a simpler version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38e47558866ed8b5).

Comment: Your example works but it's missing one of the `IF` steps in my example. I've adjusted my question to use your `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT()` suggestion, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being very clear; I'm clearly struggling to define *what* my problem actually is...

Comment: Your new example works with a pair of parentheses at the end of `MACRO` and using `#define MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA()`. As things get more nested, I believe you would need to ultimately have those two things there and any nested stuff choosing a macro to call. Actually, it also works with removing the parentheses in `EATEN_COMMA()` and adding some after the first `IF()`.

Comment: Ok that works, how would this syntax work if `MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA` took parameters? I tried `#define MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(...)()` but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Jason, You can call it inside the `IF` with the parameters it needs to select a macro.

Comment: I tried defining my macro as `#define MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(...)() EATEN_COMMA()` and then defining `MACRO` as `#define MACRO(z, n, data) BOOST_PP_IF(1,MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(a,b),MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(a,b))()` but the result of `TEST(1,2,3,4)` is still just a bunch of `BOOST_PP_IIF()`s...

Comment: @Jason, The `(...)` shouldn't have parentheses after it. Also make sure `EATEN_COMMA` is a function-like macro if you're invoking it with arguments.

Comment: I still have the same problem because, say I've got a string that has the contents `abc, def`, I can't expand that because if I name it `abc EATEN_COMMA def` then it won't expand and if I call it `abc EATEN_COMMA() def` I'll get an error. How can I get around this?

Comment: @Jason, Select a macro that expands to `abc, def` in the first `IF` so it expands with the trailing `()` on the `IF`.

Comment: the problem I'm having is that the macro takes parameters, like `_PARAM1, _PARAM2`, so I'd have to do some sort of `bind` operation, which isn't allowed. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Jason, You're kind of losing me. A more specific example would be great.

Comment: I've updated my example to reflect the problem. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Jason, First, you want `n` for the loop iteration. Anyway, in this example, you can do the same thing and move the parameters outside the `IF`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/635e9fd105c89f33. You can also combine this with calling `MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA` inside the `IF` to expand it to a macro taking two arguments. Note my example also changed `TIBEATEN_COMMA()` to `EATEN_COMMA`.

Comment: thanks for all your help, that works great. I think I was missing some pretty fundamental Macro knowledge here but you really cleared it up :)

Comment: @Jason, I'm sure I gained from doing this as well, not to mention macros are a fun thought exercise. I'll update my answer to match then.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can do this without `__VA_ARGS__`. In this simple example I used a comma which is in the template argument of function `toString<int,int>()` <kbd>[Working demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab8c51c7e0c705d2)</kbd>:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define SEQUENCE (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)

#define IGNORE_ARG(arg)
#define GET_NAME(data) BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, data)
#define GET_BELOW(data) BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, data)

#define PARSE_SEQUENCE(r, data, elem)                  \
    BOOST_PP_IF(                                       \
        BOOST_PP_GREATER_EQUAL(elem, GET_BELOW(data)), \
            GET_NAME(data), IGNORE_ARG)                \
    (elem)

#define SKIP_NUMBERS_BELOW(name, below)                \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(PARSE_SEQUENCE, (name)(below), SEQUENCE)

#define TEST(name) SKIP_NUMBERS_BELOW(name, 4)

#define MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA(N) toString<N, 2 * N>() <<

template <int a, int b> // whatever, I just need a comma here.
std::string toString() {
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a) + ":" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(b) + " ";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << TEST(MACRO_CONTAINING_COMMA) "\n";
}
```