# How do I combine BOOST_PP_IF with BOOST_PP_LPAREN?

Tags: c++, boost, nested, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I'm trying to conditionally expand a macro to either "( a" or "b )", but the naive way of doing so doesn't work on either of the compilers I'm using (Microsoft C/C++ and the NDK compiler). Example:

```
// This works on both compilers, expands to ( a ) as expected
#define PARENS_AND_SUCH BOOST_PP_IF(1, BOOST_PP_LPAREN() a BOOST_PP_RPAREN(), b)

// MSVC: syntax error/unexpected end of file in macro expansion 
// NDK: unterminated argument list
#define PARENS_AND_SUCH BOOST_PP_IF(1, BOOST_PP_LPAREN() a, b)

// Desired expansion: ( a
// MSVC expansion: ( a, b )
// NDK: error: macro "BOOST_PP_IIF" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
#define PARENS_AND_SUCH BOOST_PP_IF(1, BOOST_PP_LPAREN() a, b BOOST_PP_RPAREN())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem seems to be very similar to the one in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770614/how-do-i-expand-a-macro-containing-commas-inside-a-boost-pp-if).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force the order of evaluation to conform to the expected one by abstracting out the branches of the `IF` to subdefinitions, and delay their expansion until the conditional returns a branch:

```
#define PARENS_AND_SUCH BOOST_PP_CAT(PAS_, BOOST_PP_IF(1, THEN, ELSE))
#define PAS_THEN BOOST_PP_LPAREN() a
#define PAS_ELSE b BOOST_PP_RPAREN()
```

Since `THEN` and `ELSE` aren't complete names, the branches will not be expanded before the `IF` is expanded; when it returns, the value is combined with `PAS_` to form a new valid definition and will expand at that time.

You could also parameterise the `THEN` and `ELSE` macros and make this technique more general (and IMO more elegant): passing parameters to an incomplete name essentially forms a thunk, and works pretty much the same way (the incomplete function-like macro name will be passed around plus parameter list until it's completed).